# Spring embedded ActiveMQ, how to configure queue

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I define the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` in the Spring context, and define it as a Camel Component as follows

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("jms1")
public JmsComponent jms1() {
    ConnectionFactory f = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost:7777");
    return JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(f);
}
```

Spring will automatically start ActiveMQ JMS server on the local VM, listening on port 7777. But how do I configure a named queue on the server? I would like to `@Autowire` the queue anywhere I need it, like retrieving it from JNDI in the Java EE world.

Comment: You might consider just letting the broker auto-create the queues for you. See more in the [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-create-new-destinations.html).

Answer (score 0):

here is an example below, you need to add tcp Connector to the broker by defining the broker bean.

By default AMQ supports jndi.

take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQDestination;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class ActiveMQConfigurationWithJndi {
    public static final String DESTINATION_NAME = "TEST";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(ActiveMQConfigurationWithJndi.class, args);
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            String factoryName = "ConnectionFactory";
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
            props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://localhost:61616");
            props.put("queue." + DESTINATION_NAME, DESTINATION_NAME);
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
            ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup(factoryName);
            ActiveMQQueue dest = (ActiveMQQueue) ic.lookup(DESTINATION_NAME);
            conn = cf.createConnection();
            conn.start();
            Session session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(dest);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("textt");
            producer.send(message);
            System.out.println("ok");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
        final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
        broker.addConnector("vm://localhost:7777");
        broker.setPersistent(false);
        broker.setDestinations(new ActiveMQDestination[] { queue() });
        return broker;
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQDestination queue() {
        return new ActiveMQQueue(DESTINATION_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("jms1")
    public JmsComponent jms1() {
        return JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(jmsConnectionFactory());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example shows how to open a connection and send an email. The OP request was about pre-configuring a queue.